# Non-static method requires a target

Tags: content-search, solr

Recently migrated from Lucene to Solr search(7.2.1) in Sitecore.

When I try to get the search results from Code, I'm getting the exception

> Non-static method requires a target

However, from Solr Admin, for the same index, I'm able to get the results in Query window.

Please help.
[image]

Comment: Try changing the order of `Select(s => s.GetItem())` and `ToList()`, so the line will be `query.ToList().Select(s => s.GetItem());`

Comment: This confusing exception could be when "s" is null. Try filter it before selection:
query.Where(x=>x != null).Select(s => s.GetItem()).ToList();

Comment: Check your search logs to see what search is being executed and try executing exactly that search in your Solr Admin. Do you get the expected results?

Comment: Did you were able to find the solution, I'm struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with your model class SiteBaseSearchEntity which is not defined as `static`.

[Rob Ahnemann](http://rockpapersitecore.com/2020/07/non-static-method-requires-a-target/) had the same issue with their model:

```
public class XConnectFormDataModel
    {
        public XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            var builder = new XdbModelBuilder(nameof(XConnectFormDataModel), new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
            builder.DefineFacet<Contact, FormDataFacet>(FormDataFacet.FacetKey);
      
      builder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
            return builder.BuildModel();
    }
}
```

and the solution was to just add the `static` keyword in front of model:

```
public class XConnectFormDataModel
    {
        public **static** XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            var builder = new XdbModelBuilder(nameof(XConnectFormDataModel), new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
            builder.DefineFacet<Contact, FormDataFacet>(FormDataFacet.FacetKey);
      
      builder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
            return builder.BuildModel();
    }
}
```